# Read CSV file Swift Terminal Project

Tags: ios, swift, csv, terminal

I have this little project, which I need to read 2 csv files in Swift,
but I guess since its a Terminal application, I can't read it as I do it in IOS.

How can I read it?

already tried:

```
let file_manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let data: NSData = file_manager.contentsAtPath("./test/users.csv")!
let seq_file = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(seq_file)

let string = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: "./test/users.csv", encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
print(string)
```

But since I can't mark Target Membership of any of these files, doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to your Copy Files as shown on the screenshot

[image: Screenshow]

To get the path:

```
let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let path = bundle.pathForResource("users", ofType: "csv")
```

Comment: But my path can change, lets say if another computer acess the program. @Lennet

Comment: Nice, i can use it for tests, but ,let me explain better. I need to load a file , wich gonna be inputed by user, ate the same level as my proj. @Lennet

Comment: let the user pass the absolute path to the file as an argument